# Need Help in Creating a Regular Expression for this Scenario

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse some information from lines of texts that follow a certain formatting layout. This is an example of how the text file would look:

```
A. This is option a              C. This is option c
B. This is option b              D. This is option d
```

At the end of the day, all I want is that after parsing the above two lines, I would then have on my C# code:

```
string OptionA = "This is option a";
string OptionB = "This is option b";
string OptionC = "This is option c";
string OptionD = "This is option d";
```

The space between A. and C. (or B. and D.) could either be a tab (\t) or a random number of white spaces. When stepping through the code and the line is read, this is how it looks:

```
"A.\tThis is option a\tC. This is option c"
```

Or it may look like this

```
"A.\tThis is option a        C. This is option c"
```

I probably need some help splitting this line based on "\t" or a number of white spaces preceeding "C." as in the case of the above example.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do it,

```
@"^([A-Z])[.](.+[^\s])\s+([A-Z])[.](.+)$"
```

Where for each line

- Groups[0] is the whole line
- Groups[1] is the first letter (e.g. A)
- Groups[2] is the first option (e.g. This is option a)
- Groups[3] is the second letter (e.g. C)
- Groups[4] is the second option(e.g. This is option c)

Comment: Thanks on your response. I'll give it a try and will let you know the result.

Comment: The above regex worked as suggested. To parse each information I just simply followed the notes he described below the regex. Thanks a lot Richard!

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a whirl:

```
[A-Z]\..*((\s){2,}|\t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z][.]\s[\w\s]*\s
```

Will give you results like `A. This is option a` which you can then parse to grab the option letter and resulting text. You will also likely want to remove trailing whitespace from the lines with `.Trim()`